# Multiple files encrypted with multiple GPG keys - how to easily add/remove/manage keys, automate key change tasks?

Tags: security, encryption, gpg, pgp, gnupg

We have a bunch of files that contain sensitive information, that need to be accessed by several teams, but need to be unreadable to everyone else. Currently, each team member needs to generate their own GPG key pair and share their public key with the team.

Then whoever has access to the files will add the new person's key to the relevant files. This is a fiddly and time-consuming process. Same when a key needs to be removed from files (say, the person has left the company).

This could be automated, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Are there any tools that automate the process I've described?

Comment: You could write scripts for that, I suppose, but I've never heard of anyone doing this. Why not use encrypted storage with proper access controls?

Comment: Writing scripts is definitely doable, I just didn't want to replicate existing software, if any. Encrypted storage sounds like a good idea, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: [pass, "the standard unix password manager"](https://www.passwordstore.org/) is a program to encrypt (and whenever necessary reencrypt) multiple files with multiple GPG keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Git, you can use Blackbox : [Blackbox Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox#commands)

Blackbox is a command-line tool designed to help manage secrets, in a secure way. Blackbox encrypts files that contain sensitive data, and only authorised users with the encryption key can decrypt the files and access the secrets inside. These files are encrypted using GPG keys.